# Numerical integration of Sievert integral

Tags: integration

$$F(x, Θ) = \large \int_0^Θ \large e^{-\frac{x}{cos(Θ)}} dΘ$$

How should I use the Trapezoidial or Simpsons rule to verify that $F(0.5 , \frac{π}{2})≈0,643694$

Comment: Is the numerator of the integrand really $x$?

Comment: This seems...off. Maybe you mean $F(x,\Theta)=\int_0^\Theta e^{-x/\cos(\theta)} d \theta$? If so, surely that approximation should depend on $\Theta$ (seeing as, at the very least, it goes to zero as $\Theta$ goes to zero). Is it possible you meant something like $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}$? (When I ask Matlab for that, I get 0.643693805863748 which seems consistent with what you want, and $\pi/2$ is the first singularity...)

Comment: @Ian yeah I mean't $π/2$ ,  maybe it's time for bed....

Comment: OK, so you want that. Well, unless you can bound the second derivative of the integrand with respect to $\theta$ (which sounds hard), you should probably try to use adaptive quadrature. Or just brute force and hope it's accurate.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\cos\theta}\right)\,d\theta&\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta}{=}&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sin\theta}\right)\,d\theta\\&\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\arcsin u}{=}&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2u}\right)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du\\&\stackrel{u\mapsto\frac{1}{v}}{=}&\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-v/2}}{v\sqrt{v^2-1}}\,dv\\&\stackrel{v\mapsto t+1}{=}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t/2}}{(t+1)\sqrt{t(t+2)}}\,dt\\&\stackrel{t\mapsto z^2}{=}&\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{-z^2/2}}{(z^2+1)\sqrt{z^2+2}}\,dz\\&=&\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e}}\,\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(X^2+1)\sqrt{X^2+2}}\right]\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $X$ is the standard [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). It follows that the given integral can be easily numerical evaluated through [Monte Carlo methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).

Answer (score 0):

First arrange it a bit:

$$F(x, \Theta) = -x\int_0^{\Theta} \frac{d\Theta}{\cos\Theta}$$

The use the trapezoidal rule, which reads:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx \approx (b-a)\left(\frac{F(b) - F(a)}{2}\right)$$

What you need is just the integral of $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ which is $$\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$

This is $F(x)$, now calculate $F(b) - F(a)$

Try to go on now!

**This answer is not valid anymore due to the modification of the question; I leave it here, waiting for editing it later.**

Comment: I messed up the integral, it's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to compute $I=\int_0^L f(x) dx$ where $f$ is a smooth function whose quantitative regularity (e.g. second derivative bounds) you do not know. One way to do this carefully is with the adaptive trapezoidal rule. The main idea is the simple observation that if the trapezoidal rule with step size $h$ is given by $T(h)$, then $T(h) \approx I+a h^2$ and $T(h/2) \approx I+a h^2/4$. Thus $ah^2 \approx \frac{4}{3}(T(h)-T(h/2))$, and $ah^2$ is the approximate (signed) error in $T(h)$. The general technique we're using here is called *Richardson extrapolation*. Notice that in it we never need to know what $a$ is, only that it is the same number in both $T(h)$ and $T(h/2)$.

Thus we can do the following: take an initial mesh, for instance just $\{ 0,L \}$. On each subinterval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ of the initial mesh, compute the (normalized) error estimate $\frac{4}{3} \left | \frac{f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})}{2} - \frac{f(x_i)+2f(m_i) + f(x_{i+1})}{4} \right |=\frac{1}{3} \left | f(x_i)-2f(m_i)+f(x_{i+1})\right |$. Here $m_i=\frac{x_i+x_{i+1}}{2}$. If it exceeds $\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon L$ is your error tolerance for error of the overall integral, then you keep $m_i$ in the mesh. Then you recursively decide whether to refine on $[x_i,m_i]$ and $[m_i,x_{i+1}]$, using the same procedure. If instead the error estimate is small enough, then you just return $\frac{f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})}{2}$, to be summed up in the overall integral.

Note that this method is not quite perfect. The approximation $T(h)-I \approx \frac{4}{3} \left ( T(h)-T(h/2) \right )$ is only good enough to guarantee refinement when it is appropriate if $h$ is already sufficiently small. Thus some limited amount of quantitative regularity should ideally be obtained in advance before using a method like this. Consider for instance $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x)^2 dx$ with the initial $h=2\pi$. The method checks the midpoint $\pi$, finds that the function is also zero there just as it is at the endpoints. Then it basically concludes that the integrand is close enough to being identically zero, and so it immediately returns $0$, which is nowhere near the correct answer.